# Is there any point in using Gmail alias to prevent spam?

Tags: gmail

I'm thinking of starting another Gmail account for the "less important" things that I need to register with (random websites, subscriptions etc)

That is until I realized you can use Gmail alias.

But whilst I think it will be useful for re-routing things to seperate folders, is it useful for keeping out spam?

I would've thought all spammers need to do is to add a rule - "if domain == gmail.com, then remove everything after the plus sign" in order to get to your real address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spammers might possibly do that, but I doubt it. I find Gmail's spam filters are so good I don't need to worry about it.

One thing it *is* useful for is to find those companies/entities that play fast-and-loose with your e-mail address. When I get e-mail sent to myname+website1@gmail.com from some *other* website, I know that website1 gave away (or sold!) my e-mail address and I'm not likely to continue my relationship with that entity (or the site that bought it, for that matter).

Comment: You can also use periods in Gmail to create a vast number of variations of a single address for tracking offenders. example@gmail.com, e.xample@gmail.com, ex.ample@gmail.com, e.x.ample@gmail.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe email receivers can still see the senders 'official' address with an alias in the full header if they want to. I'm starting a question specific to that regarding security here: [Is it possible to make a GMail alias secure?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/141389/is-it-possible-to-make-a-gmail-alias-secure)